# jQuery return false not stopping query from running

Tags: jquery, foreach, return

I have the following code:

```
    else if($page == 'two'){
        $('[name^=q1\\[\\]] option:selected').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() < 1) {
                $('#rq1').addClass('hovered_error');
                $('#mandall').css("background-color","#901F39");
                $('#mandall').css("color","#FFF");
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

What should happen is if the .val is less than 1 - it should add the class, change the css of the ID #mandall and then stop the query.

What is actually happening is that it adds the class and changes the css of #mandall and then keeps going to submit a form - when it shouldn't - what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `return false;` from inside a `.each()` loop you are actually just breaking out of the `.each`.

You need to call `return false;` somewhere outside of your `.each` to stop the form submitting, e.g.

```
var doSubmit = true;
$('[name^=q1\\[\\]] option:selected').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() < 1) {
          doSubmit = false;
          return false;
        }
});
if(!doSubmit) return false;
```

Comment: Thanks for that but clearly there must be something very odd going on with my code as adding this, still doesn't work. :-(

Comment: @Homer_J - What runs that code? You've obviously only shown half of your function since you start with an `else...`

Comment: All sorted - yep, needed to place the second return false, properly outside the else loop

Answer (score 3):

It is because you are returning the value from a callback method(`each`), which will not result in a return from the caller method(your submit callback).

```
else if($page == 'two'){
    var valid = true;
    $('[name^=q1\\[\\]] option:selected').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() < 1) {
            $('#rq1').addClass('hovered_error');
            $('#mandall').css("background-color","#901F39");
            $('#mandall').css("color","#FFF");
            valid = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    if(!valid){
        returnf false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers for taking the time to respond.